# DataBinding happens only first time

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I have two User Controls in my window, both are bound to the same context.

One of them is getting updated and the other is not.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Can you please provide your Xaml so we do not have to guess? Thanks :)

Comment: @HiTech Magic : I Hope that i'm not being rude but the code private (not mine) and I can't just copy it ti here. I've tried to create this bug in a new solution but failed. What I can tell is that the binding is being set by code. 

My Question is in general - How could it be that binding happen only once ?

Comment: Is the answer below? If so please mark it so.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an issue with the bindings.  Make sure your dependency properties bound to each control are both getting notified via OnPropertyChanged. If both properties aren't getting notified this would be your issue regardless if they share the same datacontext (viewmodel).

Blessings,

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Beware of UserControls by default they bind one way you have to specify TwoWay:

```
<Binding Mode="TwoWay" ...>
...
</Binding>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you see any binding errors in the Output window? If so you can post that and maybe we can understand.

If not try to put a dummy converter in the binding and see if its methods are hit.

One from the multiple issues could be binding source address is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, we only guess:

Check that the property names in the bindings are an exact match (including case). It is quite common to have typing errors that cause bindings to fail (silently).